# France Schengen visa 30 day duration but valid for 3 months?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, schengen-visas

I recently have been issued a France schengen visa which is valid from 16-03-18 to 16-06-18 with a 30 day duration of stay and it is multiple entry, but.. I'm confused is the visa valid for 30 days or 3 months?

Does that mean I can go enter France on 16-03 stay there for a week exit and then enter again in April or May?

Comment: I am not sure about France  schengen visa, but I have a B1/B2 US Visa. It will be validated thru 10 year with duration of 180 days with multi entries. What means? During these 10 years, I can go multi times and I can stay no more then 180 days. So, answering your question. Yes, you can stay 30 days, exit and reenter. However, you should have a explanation for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the Schengen 'duration of intended stay' and 'duration of visa validity' the same?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70882/are-the-schengen-duration-of-intended-stay-and-duration-of-visa-validity-the)

Comment: If it's a multiple entry visa then you certainly can otherwise you can have a look at the question @MarcelP. pointed out

Comment: @MarcelP. What are you talking about?  US multiple-entry B visas do not typically say anything about duration of stay, but B visitors normally get six months on entry, not 180 days.  US border officers can actually grant up to 1 year on entry if the visitor can meet certain criteria.  Does your visa have some nonstandard annotation or something like that?  In any event, US visas work rather differently from Schengen visas, most notably in that a US visa's expiration date has nothing to do with when the bearer must leave the country.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. It is valid for three months. Any number of entries after 16-03-18 inclusive but before 16-06-18 inclusive, into any Schengen states.

You have to exit Schengen area by the end of the day on 16-06-18, and you can stay no more than 30 days total. I.e. if you spent all your days you can't enter or stay anymore, even if visa is still valid date-wise.

To be on a safe side, count every time you entered as a separate day, even if you did multiple entries in one day.

Comment: It is not necessary to count multiple entries on a single day as multiple days.